# Exception handling after migration from Spring Kafka 2.6 to 2.8+

Tags: spring-kafka

Recently I’ve updated Spring Boot to 2.7.10 and Spring Kafka to 2.8.11 (it was 2.4.5 and 2.6.7 accordingly) and ran into a different behavior in exception handling. I use the  *RecordInterceptor* that checks some cases and if that check is false then throws an exception. In earlier version it led to message re-read until case check becomes true or amount of retries is exhausted. The new version behavior is different: a message re-read is never occurred.

I’ve found in the code difference:

The *earlyRecordInterceptor* is now not null (The reason is that *isInterceptBeforeTx* is now *true* by default). Running *checkEarlyIntercept()* leads to following case: when Exception is thrown within *RecordInterceptor* it’s caught by that block in *run()* method:

```
catch (Exception e) {

   handleConsumerException(e);

}
```

It leads to logging the exception and stop of further process.

In earlier version *earlyRecordInterceptor* was null so the *checkEarlyIntercept()* didn’t invoke *RecordInterceptor*’s intercept. it was invoked later in the *doInvokeRecordListener* method. In that case a thrown exception within *RecordInterceptor* was handled by the *invokeErrorHandler*, where the exception was decorated in *ListenerExecutionFailedException*, which led to further message re-read process as I suppose.

I’ve tried to set *interceftBeforeTx = false* to emulate previous behavior:

```
factory.setContainerCustomizer(container -> container.setInterceptBeforeTx(false));
```

But there is second check in *earlyRecordInterceptor* assignment *kafkaTxManager == null*, so the *interceftBeforeTx* property didn’t change anything.

Is the behavior correct?  What should I do to get previous version behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in 2.9.x (current is 2.9.9).

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2329

2.8.x is out of OSS support; you should use 2.9.x with Boot 2.7.x.

https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#support

Matrix: https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Gary!

I’ve upgraded to *2.9.9*, but the result is still the same.

I’ve made a [MCRE](https://github.com/AntonLazarev/early-interceptor-ex-mcre), there is a test `MyKafkaListenerTest` that fails if the versions of Spring Boot and Spring Kafka are set to *2.7.13* and *2.9.9* accordingly. And it runs successfully if the versions are set to *2.4.5* and *2.6.7*.

I’ll be glad if you could take a look at that case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the reproducer. After further review, it was not expected that interceptors would throw exceptions. But I do accept that it is a behavior change and should be corrected. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2722

Comment: Thanks, Gary! Could you please advise a proper way to throw an exception when you need to re-read a message after that? For instance: I've some business-rule check-up and if it's false an exception should be thrown, then the message should be re-read and that  business-rule check-up should occur again, until it will come true or a message read retries will be exhausted.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; after the fix is applied, it will work the same way as before.

Comment: Sorry for the confused question. You wrote earlier that it was not expected that the interceptors would throw exceptions, so I’m interested what is the right way to handle one business logic across all the @KafkaListeners, which can lead to an exceptional situation?

Comment: I should have used "anticipated" rather than "expected"; it was just a miss with the implementation. The original request to implement interceptors was for much simpler use cases; e.g. setting up logging MDC. What you are doing is fine, we just didn't design for that use case. Another technique would have been to add an advice to the container's advice chain; then, from the container's perspective, that code would be part of the listener itself, rather than an interceptor which is invoked before calling the listener. But, as I said, what you are doing is ok.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was a little bit confused by your initial reply about interceptors  Should I already mark this question as solved or I need to wait for a new release for retest?

Comment: You can test it with 2.9.10-SNAPSHOT or 3.0.9-SNAPSHOT (the releases are scheduled for next Monday).